# Where can I set my preferred advertisement language?

Tags: feature-request, advertising, localization

So I got this ad. It's in German.

[image: German ad]

Okay, cool, I get it, I updated my profile that I live in Germany now. But I really don't wish to see ads in German. My native tongue is Dutch, and on an all English sites I prefer the ads and doodads in English.

My accept language header is `Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7`

It shows Dutch as primary, and as backup English. I like it that way. That's the way I'd like to see it.

---

Based on [Cœur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur)'s comment: 
He suggested it might be based upon IP. But I saw this ad at work, my work is in the Netherlands and the company I work for has a Dutch ISP giving us an Dutch IP
[image]

My Whois data

```html
<pre>
% This is the RIPE Database query service.  
% The objects are in RPSL format.  
%  
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.  
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf  
 
% Note: this output has been filtered.  
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.  
 
 % Information related to '2001:***:***::/36'
   
% Abuse contact for '2001:***:***::/36' is 'abuse@xs4all.nl'  
  
inet6num:       2001:***:***::/36
netname:        NL-XS4ALL-BROADBANDPOOL-14  
descr:          XS4ALL BROADBAND POOL 14  
country:        NL  
admin-c:        XS42-RIPE  
tech-c:         XS42-RIPE  
mnt-by:         XS4ALL-MNT  
status:         AGGREGATED-BY-LIR  
assignment-size: 48  
remarks:        Please send email to "abuse@xs4all.nl" for complaints  
remarks:        regarding portscans, DoS attacks and spam.  
created:        2012-08-03T11:47:48Z  
last-modified:  2012-08-03T11:47:48Z  
source:         RIPE  Filtered  
   
role:           XS4ALL Internet NOC  
address:        XS4ALL Internet BV  
address:        Postbus 1848  
address:        1000BV Amsterdam  
address:        The Netherlands  
phone:          +31 20 3987654  
fax-no:         +31 20 3987604  
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@xs4all.nl  
admin-c:        CB127  
admin-c:        KAI11-RIPE  
tech-c:         CB127  
tech-c:         RZ2757-RIPE  
tech-c:         KAI11-RIPE  
tech-c:         MVS5  
tech-c:         TFR-RIPE  
nic-hdl:        XS42-RIPE
mnt-by:         XS4ALL-MNT  
created:        2002-01-30T10:14:53Z  
last-modified:  2016-10-12T10:52:01Z  
source:         RIPE  Filtered  
  
% Information related to '2001:***::/******'  

route6:         2001:****::/32  
descr:          XS4ALL Networking  
origin:         AS3265  
mnt-by:         XS4ALL-MNT  
created:        2007-02-27T10:20:23Z  
last-modified:  2007-02-27T10:20:23Z  
source:         RIPE  

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.90 (ANGUS)

% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
% To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

% Information related to '82.161.200.0 - 82.161.***.255'

% Abuse contact for '82.161.***.0 - 82.161.***.255' is 'removed email address'

inetnum: 82.161.***.0 - 82.161.***.255
netname: XS4ALL
descr: XS4ALL Internet BV
descr: in NSA: wdsl-pool-
country: NL
admin-c: XS42-RIPE
tech-c: XS42-RIPE
status: ASSIGNED PA
remarks: Please send email to "removed email address" for complaints
remarks: regarding portscans, DoS attacks and spam.
mnt-by: XS4ALL-MNT
created: 2012-07-09T13:46:19Z
last-modified: 2012-07-09T13:46:19Z
source: RIPE # Filtered

role: XS4ALL Internet NOC
address: XS4ALL Internet BV
address: Postbus 1848
address: 1000BV Amsterdam
address: The Netherlands
phone:  removed phone number
fax-no:  removed phone number
abuse-mailbox:  removed email address
admin-c: CB127
admin-c: KAI11-RIPE
tech-c: CB127
tech-c: RZ2757-RIPE
tech-c: KAI11-RIPE
tech-c: MVS5
tech-c: TFR-RIPE
nic-hdl: XS42-RIPE
mnt-by: XS4ALL-MNT
created: 2002-01-30T10:14:53Z
last-modified: 2016-10-12T10:52:01Z
source: RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '82.161.0.0/16AS3265'

route: 82.161.0.0/16
descr: XS4ALL Internet routing
origin: AS3265
mnt-by: XS4ALL-MNT
created: 2009-02-12T12:45:45Z
last-modified: 2011-02-08T14:59:21Z
source: RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.90 (ANGUS)
</pre>
```

Can either Stack Overflow obey the accept language header, or give me a setting in my profile where I can select a display language?

Comment: Note that I see ads in Japanese when my IP is in Japan. So it's IP based and there is likely no current alternative except changing your IP for a different country (think: VPN).

Comment: Can I set my ad language to MoonSpeak?

Comment: It makes no sense if it's IP based @Cœur because I saw this ad from the netherlands, because I work in the netherlands and the company I work for has an Dutch ISP

Comment: Make a whois on your IP and provide the data. Maybe there is something wrong and there is a "Germany" hidden?

Comment: Why does SO allow non-English advertising anyway? It is an international site and anyone who seek to work as a programmer must know basic English. If they don't, they cannot function as programmers and cannot be hired.

Comment: @lundin because it's advertising? An ad in your langage can have more chances to impress/intrigue you.

Comment: @Lundin Because "knowing basic English" not equals to "willing to work for an English-language-based company"?

Comment: Well... it might be clever to advertise in English if the work requires English. Otherwise you always get the "fluent in English" applications, and then when you suddenly switch to English during the interview, you find that the candidate who claimed to be fluent can barely speak a word. But yeah, I can see how large, multi-national company that uses English even for everyday internal communication would be unappealing to many.

Comment: @rekire no germany hidden added the whois data to the question. And in europe that would be a really big faux pas for another country to show up in the ip listing of another countries provided ip address. Not to mention a couple of laws that would disagree with that.

Comment: Do you know the Paint Bucket tool in your image editing software?